# How can I read the delivery class of a table?

Tags: abap

I want to write a program to show critical Transports e.g with changes on Tables with very many items.

For that i should differentiate between Customizing and Workbench Tables.

My Problem is that i have not yet find a Function or something to read that Flag of the Table. I did debug the Transaction SE11 while editing the Flag but i have not yet found the spot where it writes it in the Database or gets it out of it.
The only mark I found were the 2 attributes `DF-DDXX` and `DD02D`, which hold the flag and which get changed when one edits it, but till now I have not been able to find the spot at witch it is written in the database or used in a function or so.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some hints on writing a good-quality question.

Comment: What do you classify as a "workbench table" in contrast to a "customizing table"?

Comment: Yeah sorry i just created my account so i'm not really expierienced with how to ask questions here, i will try to do it better next time but Jagger already helped me out with my Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The info you are looking for is stored in the transparent table `DD02L`, field `CONTFLAG`.

So if you want to search for all the customizing tables' names for example, here would be the query.

```
DATA: lt_tabname TYPE tttabname.

SELECT tabname
  FROM dd02l
  INTO TABLE lt_tabname
  WHERE contflag = 'C'.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped me out

Comment: Your welcome, happy to have helped. When you have enough reputation, do not forget to upvote as well. ;)